# Django ModelForm validated without submitting

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form on my home page.  My view for that looks like this:

```
from djangoproject1.authentication import forms
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def main(request):
    uf = forms.UserForm()
    upf = forms.UserProfileForm()
    return render_to_response("authentication/index.html", {'form1': uf, 'form2':upf})

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uf = forms.UserForm(request.POST)
        upf = forms.UserProfileForm(request.POST)
        if uf.is_valid() and upf.is_valid():
            user = uf.save(commit=False)
            user.set_password(uf.cleaned_data["password"])
            user.save()
            userprofile = upf.save(commit=False)
            userprofile.user = user
            userprofile.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/register-success/")
    return render_to_response("authentication/index.html", {'form1': uf,'form2':upf})
```

It makes one form with these two parts.  When I launch my browser however, all the error messages already appear.  I thought this left them unbound and therefore they wouldn't try and be validated since I didn't post anything.

Here's the form code:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from djangoproject1.authentication.models import UserProfile     

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    cpassword = forms.PasswordInput()

    def clean(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['cpassword']!=self.cleaned_data['password']:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email','password',)

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('phonenumber',)
```

Here's the html:

```
<h1>Register</h1>
    <form action="/register/" method="post">
        {{ form1.as_p }}
        {{ form2.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
```

Comment: That's not possible with the code you've shown us. Is this really the full view you're using? Show your template code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't errors but help texts.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've described, it seems as if you're hitting the `register` view with an invalid POST. But you say this is happening on the `main` view when you go to the page?

There shouldn't be any form errors with an unbound form (like `main` would return) but they would show up on a bound form after a failed `is_valid` call in `register`.

The one thing I can see is that your `clean` method on `UserForm` doesn't `return self.cleaned_data`.

It might make things a bit easier to troubleshoot if you temporarily change the name of one of the templates and make sure you are getting the view you think you are.